# I could do two different NavDrawers in the same Android App?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

my problem is that:

I want to make a login service in my application and depending on which user logs in, go to a different NavDrawer activity. In Android Studio when you create the NavDrawer activity that comes by default, it generates one perfectly. But when I want to generate a different one, having the same name doesn't create anything.

The only way I have found is by refactoring everything generated by the Android Studio wizard and changing all the names of the layouts.

I would like to know if there is an easier way to create another NavDrawer without having to refactor so much and without so many errors.

Thank you!

NavDrawers Generated

[image]

Conceptual Scheme

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Solved, you only need to make an instance of one of these nav drawers and then extend that to another one.